# Unzipping files in Python

Tags: python, zip, unzip, python-zipfile

I read through the [`zipfile` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), but couldn't understand how to *unzip* a file, only how to zip a file. How do I unzip all the contents of a zip file into the same directory?

Comment: Related: unzipping files recursively https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339000/unzip-zip-files-in-folders-and-subfolders-with-python & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285502/how-to-extract-zip-file-recursively-in-python

Comment: For a one line extraction, see [`shutil.unpack_archive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive).

Comment: @fonini answer is -- as of 2021 -- the right/best one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64110098/687896

Answer (score 1651, accepted):

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
```

That's pretty much it!

Comment: what if the contents of the .zip archive are same, in all .zip archives?
how to rename the content before extracting? example: 1.zip 2.zip.. all contain content.txt : extract all like 1content.txt 2content.txt?

Comment: @iratzhash I typically create a new temporary directory for the contents using tempfile: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html
I unzip to the temporary directory and the move / organize the files from there.

Comment: @3kstc I would `from zipfile import ZipFile`. When using it, you no longer need to use `zipfile.ZipFile`, and can use `ZipFile(zip_file_name)`.

Comment: @iratzhash I realize you commented 1.5 years ago. But just so others know, usually contents within a zip file are read-only. A good answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428318/rename-files-in-zip-folder-using-zipmodule?lq=1) by "bouke"

Comment: thnx, note: There is no zipfile library, no need to pip install, zipfile is already there...

Comment: I'd add: `from tempfile import mkdtemp; directory_to_extract_to = mkdtemp()`

Comment: for passwords use:

with ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zipObj:
                zipObj.extractall(output_folder, pwd=b'myPassword')

Comment: This minimal code will still do the job without problem:
`z = ZipFile(path_to_zip_file)`
`z.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)`

Answer (score 419):

If you are using *Python 3.2* or later:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip","r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("targetdir")
```

You dont need to use the *close* or *try/catch* with this as it uses the
[context manager](http://eigenhombre.com/2013/04/20/introduction-to-context-managers/) construction.

Comment: ZipFile also works as a context manager in 2.7 or later: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile

Comment: How to deal with https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.BadZipFile exception? Generally, what is the best practice to use try/except with context manager (with-statement)?

Comment: `zipfile` + `pathlib` = win. mind if i slightly update your answer?

Comment: is there a reason to avoid `os.system(f'tar -xvzf {filename}')` and instead use zipfile (e.g. `zip = ZipFile('file.zip'); zip.extractall() )` or `shutil.unpack_archive(filename, extract_dir)`?

Comment: @CharlieParker The main reason is portability. `system` calls are OS dependent. For example, `tar` would not be available on Windows.

Comment: I do not recommend zipfile. I had problems to extract files added in existing zip file. This can be done with total commander, which addz new file entry and file database at the end of the file. `zipfile` extracted only the old files. `shutil.unpack_archive` does not have this problem.

Answer (score 167):

[`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) is a somewhat low-level library. Unless you need the specifics that it provides, you can get away with [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)'s higher-level functions [`make_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) and [`unpack_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive).

`make_archive` is already described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650295) answer. As for `unpack_archive`:

```py
import shutil
shutil.unpack_archive(filename, extract_dir)
```

`unpack_archive` detects the compression format automatically from the "extension" of `filename` (`.zip`, `.tar.gz`, etc), and so does `make_archive`. Also, `filename` and `extract_dir` can be any [path-like](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/) objects (e.g. [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instances) since Python 3.7.

Comment: This method doesn't work when the zip file has a custom extension, e.g. (`.omt` for OmegaT project packages). It gives `raise ReadError("Unknown archive format '{0}'".format(filename))`.

Comment: @msoutopico you can specify thje format explicitly: `shutil.unpack_archive(filename, extract_dir, format)`

Comment: what is wrong with `os.system(f'tar -xvzf {path2zip} -C {path2unzip}/')`?

Comment: @CharlieParker you have already asked the same thing in a comment to another answer, and that comment was answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python/64110098?noredirect=1#comment119468939_36662770 `os.system` is not portable, opens up security issues, is harder to use correctly (e.g. your proposal fails when the paths have special characters), and is less readable.

Comment: This solution doesn’t seem to maintain executable bits on the stuff inside the archive as it’s unzipped?

Answer (score 50):

Use the `extractall` method, if you're using Python 2.6+

```
zip = ZipFile('file.zip')
zip.extractall()
```

Comment: Don't you have to specify a destination (zip.extractall(destination))?

Comment: Not if you're just extracting into the same directory as the zipfile

Comment: @DanGayle this appears to be extracting the zip file into the current working directory, NOT the location of the zip file

Comment: for me, ZipFile() didn't work but zipfile.ZipFile() did - after import zipfile

Comment: You need to `zip.close()` at the end if you don't use a `with` statement like the other answers suggest.

Comment: what is wrong with `os.system(f'tar -xvzf {path2zip} -C {path2unzip}/')`?

Comment: to which directory is this extracted to?

Answer (score 24):

**You can also import only `ZipFile`:**

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
zf = ZipFile('path_to_file/file.zip', 'r')
zf.extractall('path_to_extract_folder')
zf.close()
```

Works in *Python 2* and *Python 3*.

Comment: Thank you for your attention @MylesHollowed

However, this is not a copy from the accepted answer. I agree that they are similar to each other, but they are different. This is also indicated by your comment, because the accepted one is definitely better for you than mine. If it was a copy, it would be the same...

For someone my answer may be valuable because it is perhaps more readable and as you noticed import less code...
It is because of these differences that I decided to put my answer to give an alternative. Is not that why we can put other answers after accepting one?
All the best

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? Why did someone give her a negative point? After all, it is the answer to the question and is distinguished by its simplicity compared to other answers, which may be important for some people who are looking for an answer. Isn't it?

Comment: @MylesHollowed  `import zipfile.ZipFile` generates `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zipfile.ZipFile'; 'zipfile' is not a package` in 3.6.5.  I am open to it being operator error on my part, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @MikeF I had the same problem with Python 3.8.5 but the workaround was to use `from zipfile import ZipFile`.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to do it in shell, instead of writing code.

```
 python3 -m zipfile -e myfiles.zip myfiles/
```

`myfiles.zip` is the zip archive and `myfiles` is the path to extract the files.

Comment: why not just do `tar -xvzf path_file` in your case?

Comment: ZIP files are not tar files.  Unless you have a special version of `tar` which handles ZIP archives, your command wont work at all.  `tar` with the `-z` option processes gzipped tar archives (generally files with extensions `.tgz` or `.tar.gz`)

Answer (score 13):

try this :

```
import zipfile
def un_zipFiles(path):
    files=os.listdir(path)
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            filePath=path+'/'+file
            zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(filePath)
            for names in zip_file.namelist():
                zip_file.extract(names,path)
            zip_file.close()
```

path : unzip file's path

Answer (score 13):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
ZipFile("YOURZIP.zip").extractall("YOUR_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY")
```

The directory where you will extract your files doesn't need to exist before, you name it at this moment

YOURZIP.zip is the name of the zip if your project is in the same directory.
If not, use the PATH i.e : C://....//YOURZIP.zip

Think to escape the `/` by an other `/` in the PATH
If you have a `permission denied` try to launch your ide (i.e: Anaconda) as administrator

YOUR_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY will be created in the same directory than your project

Comment: to me it's strictly similar

Answer (score 2):

```
import os 
zip_file_path = "C:\AA\BB"
file_list = os.listdir(path)
abs_path = []
for a in file_list:
    x = zip_file_path+'\\'+a
    print x
    abs_path.append(x)
for f in abs_path:
    zip=zipfile.ZipFile(f)
    zip.extractall(zip_file_path)
```

This does not contain validation for the file if its not zip. If the folder contains non .zip file it will fail.