# Unzip zip files in folders and subfolders

Tags: python, unzip

I try to unzip 150  zip files. All the zip files as different names, and they all spread in one big folder that divided to a lot of sub folders and sub sub folders.i want to extract each archive to separate folder with the same name as the original zip file name and also in the same place as the original zip file . my code is:

```
import zipfile    
import os,os.path,sys  

pattern = '*.zip'  
folder = r"C:\Project\layers"   
files_process = []  
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(r"C:\Project\layers"):  
    for filenames in files:  
        if filenames == pattern:  
            files_process.append(os.path.join(root, filenames))  
            zip.extract()
```

After i run the code nothing happened.
Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Using `zipfile` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html

Comment: [extract_zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

UPDATE:

Finally, this code worked for me:

```
import zipfile,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"C:\Project"
pattern = '*.zip'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
        zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, filename)).extractall(os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(filename)[0]))
```

Comment: Use `os.path.splitext(filename)[0]` instead of `filename.split('.')[0]` The latter return a wrong result if there are multiple dots in the filename.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Path.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to enumerate zip-files recursively and [`shutil.unpack_archive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive) to unpack zip files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import unpack_archive

zip_files = Path(r"C:\Project\layers").rglob("*.zip")
while True:
    try:
        path = next(zip_files)
    except StopIteration:
        break # no more files
    except PermissionError:
        logging.exception("permission error")
    else:
         extract_dir = path.with_name(path.stem)
         unpack_archive(str(path), str(extract_dir), 'zip')
```

It *"extract[s] each archive to separate folder with the same name as the original zip file name and also in the same place as the original zip file"* e.g., it extracts `'layers/dir/file.zip'` archive into `'layers/dir/file'` directory.

Comment: i get an error:     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\desktop\python.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
ImportError: No module named pathlib

Comment: i using python 2.7.8 shell

Comment: @Y.Y.C: there is a backport of `pathlib` for Python 2. Run [`pip install pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/) or [install Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: where i install pathlib?

Comment: @Y.Y.C: just run the `pip` command. If you don't know what the command-line is or don't know what `pip` command does; ask a separate question (or (more likely) find an existing one).

Comment: J.F.Sebastian,i must work with python 2.7.8 ,so i install path lib. but now i get en error:                                                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\yaron\shonot\software\gis\tools\YARON_SCRIPTS\unzip.py", line 3, in <module>
    from shutil import unpack_archive
ImportError: cannot import name unpack_archive

Comment: @Y.Y.C do you see `unpack_archive()` in [the documentation for `shutil` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)? You could [use zipfile module, to extract the archive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html). Use `unicode` instead of `str` for filenames on Windows.

Comment: +1 for [unpack_archive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive) and [rglob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob). Did not know of either of those.

Comment: The pathlib module for python2 is not supported anymore. The backport of pathlib for python2 is called [pathlib2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/), so you need to `pip install pathlib2` if still stuck in the 2.x era.

Comment: @Davos: note: the script has python3 shebang. You should run it using Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: Agreed, I was just adding new information to your previous comment about the backport, best to use `pathlib2` not `pathlib`

Answer (score 0):

To unzip all the files into a temporary folder (Ubuntu)

```
import tempfile
import zipfile

tmpdirname = tempfile.mkdtemp()

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/zipfile.zip')

for fn in zf.namelist():
    temp_file = tmpdirname+"/"+fn
    #print(temp_file)

    f = open(temp_file, 'w')
    f.write(zf.read(fn).decode('utf-8'))
    f.close()
```

Comment: the decoding assumes the files are text

Comment: I would encourage the usage of `os.path.join(tmpdirname, fn)` instead of `tmpdirname+"/"+fn`

Comment: You could open the temp_file as binary so you don't need to decode it, and use context manager for the file handle so you don't need the `f.close()` , e.g.  `with open(temp_file, 'wb') as f:` Even better you could replace the loop over `namelist` with the `zipfile.extractall` method and supply tmpdirname as the path. This doesn't answer the question though. The question mentions nothing about temp directories, it asks "i want to extract each archive to separate folder with the same name as the original zip file name and also **in the same place** as the original zip file"