# pip install pathlib

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip

I work with python 2.7.8 and can't change the version of python because it affect other important programs. Continuously to [Unzip zip files in folders and subfolders with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339000/unzip-zip-files-in-folders-and-subfolders-with-python#comment45037150_28345130) i don't know how to install "pip install pathlib". Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how install the `pip` executable itself (should already be installed with Python), or that you get an error when you try `pip install pathlib` to install the package? If so, paste the error message.

Comment: This question may well be a duplicate, there are many other posts on [pip install](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pip+install+) issues/errors.

Comment: In python 2, the pathlib library has been backported as pathlib2, so at the command line run `pip install pathlib2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i succeed install pathlib2 module by enter into the cmd.exe and writing:

> > > cd C:\Users\jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts pip install pathlib2

Answer (score 0):

If on windows, type this from Command Prompt to get pathlib for Python 2.7.8:
`python -m pip install pathlib2`

If you're on a unix distro, type this from BASH (any shell):
`pip install pathlib2`

If on mac, from terminal:
`sudo easy_install pip`
`pip install pathlib2`

And now you should be able to import pathlib2 (backported version of pathlib) from Python 2.7.8.