# Equivalent of os.walk() for zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I was wondering if there was a function equivalent to `os.walk()` to navigate inside a zipfile. I know that `zipfile` package provides function to list all content of a zip file, but I was not able to find a way to navigate through the zip file as one would do through a file tree with `os.walk()`.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: You could use the split method to detect dirs like the answer of @Forge on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285502/how-to-extract-zip-file-recursively-in-python , but as martineau mentioned there is nothing like os.walk

Comment: I saw on the documentation that there is a Path object (for python>=3.8), but I cannot understand what is its purpose. Could this be usefull?

Comment: Look at zipfile library, you can read a zip file and then list all entries within the file including directories and subdirectories using namelist(0 method.

Comment: See Activestate's [Zɪᴘ Wᴀʟᴋᴇʀ](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/425840-zip-walker-zip-file-tree-generator/) recipe (looks like it will need a little updating to work in Python 3.x).