# i need help to extract files from a zip file using python

Tags: python, zip, extract

i have created a zip file called shoppy and put "cats.txt" in it and now i want to extract it but my code doesn't work it gives me this error

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'extract'
```

here is my code

```
from zipfile import *

z=open("shoppy.zip","U")
z.extract("cats.txt")
```

Comment: I suggest referring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `open()` refers to the builtin function, not to any function in the `zipfile` - there is no `zipfile.open()` function.

To open a zip file use the [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) class:

```
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile('shoppy.zip')
z.extract('cats.txt')
```

This will unzip the file into the current directory. If you would prefer to unzip into a string you can use [`zipfile.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.read):

```
content = z.read('cats.txt')
```

Now `content` will contain the unzipped content of the file.