# Unzip prompted "Press 'Q' to quit, or any other key to continue"

Tags: python, unzip

I want to write a Python script to automatically unzip lots of apk files and then do static analysis. However, when I unzip some apk files, unzip prompted that "Press 'Q' to quit, or any other key to continue".

Because it's a script and I haven't press any key then the script hangs. Any command option can solve this problem? Or do I have to handle it in Python? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: How are you unzipping the files? If the "static analysis" can be done as a separate step...https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html. Here is a SO link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3451111/6655092. Otherwise, there may be an option with whatever you are using to unzip it to not request user input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't say what the structure looks like, but for a single use of unzip you can try this:

```
echo Q | unzip myfile.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same thing and figured out what's causing it. Turns out, if a zip file has a zip comment attached, it will be shown, along with a prompt that hangs your script.

Passing `-q` to `unzip` will avoid showing the comment and any hangs, though you will lose the list of files being unzipped too. I haven't figured out how to just prevent the comment from showing up and not the rest of the stuff `unzip` prints.