# How to use GloVe word-embeddings file on Google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, word-embedding

I have downloaded the data with wget

```
!wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
 - ‘glove.6B.zip’ saved [862182613/862182613]
```

It is saved as zip and I would like to use glove.6B.300d.txt file from the zip file. What I want to achieve is :

```
embeddings_index = {}
with io.open('glove.6B.300d.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:],dtype='float32')
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs
```

Of course I am having this error:

```
IOErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-d07cafc85c1c> in <module>()
      1 embeddings_index = {}
----> 2 with io.open('glove.6B.300d.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
      3     for line in f:
      4         values = line.split()
      5         word = values[0]

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'glove.6B.300d.txt'
```

How can I unzip and use that file in my code above on Google colab?

Comment: It's better to download and unzip from here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its simple, checkout this [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python) from SO.

```
import zipfile
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
zip_ref.close()
```

Comment: I would like to do this on Google colab. I do not think so glove zip is saved into my computer.

Comment: Assuming that zipfile gets into current directory as mentioned by `wget` command, just specify `glove.6B.zip` as path -- I think it should work

Comment: <pre> File "<ipython-input-60-785ab10a0dbb>", line 2
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(glove.6B.zip, 'r')
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax}<code>

Comment: This needs to be corrected to `zipfile.ZipFile("glove.6B.zip", 'r') ` you've note specified the `"` for the file name

Comment: Oh thank you and directory_to_extract_to line to extract on my computer. And instead of extracall how can I speciy one file?

Comment: Try this `zip_ref.extractall(".")`, once done you can use [os.listdir function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm) to check what all files have been extracted to current directory

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance! For now I am not experiencing any error. I am accepting your answer as a correct answer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 30):

One more way you could do is as follows.

## 1. Download the zip file

```
!wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
```

post downloading the zip file it is saved in the /content directory of google Collab.

## 2. Unzip it

```
!unzip glove*.zip
```

## 3. Get the exact path of where the embedding vectors are extracted using

```
!ls
!pwd
```

## 4. Index the vectors

```
print('Indexing word vectors.')

embeddings_index = {}
f = open('glove.6B.100d.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

print('Found %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))
```

## 5. Fuse with google - drive

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install -U -q pydrive
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null

!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
# Generate creds for the Drive FUSE library.
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}

!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

## 6. Save the indexed vectors to google drive for re-use

```
import pickle
pickle.dump({'embeddings_index' : embeddings_index } , open('drive/path/to/your/file/location', 'wb'))
```

If you have already downloaded the zip file in the local system, just extract it and upload the required dimension file to google drive -> fuse gdrive -> give the appropriate path and then use it / make an index of it, etc.

also, another way would be if already downloaded in the local system via code in collab

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
```

select the file and use it as in step 3 onwards.

This is how you can work with glove word embedding in google collaboratory. hope it helps.

Comment: If I already have the file and I try to upload it to colab, it takes a lot of time even for the 50D file. Is there another way? Also if I download the glove files using the wget method directly to colab, do I have to download everytime I open and close the notebook?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Google Drive, you can:

1. Mount your Google Drive so that it can be used from Colab notebook

   ```
   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
   ```
2. Download glove.6B.zip and extract it to a place of your choice on your Google Drive, for example

   ```
   "My Drive/Place/Of/Your/Choice/glove.6B.300d.txt"
   ```
3. Open the file directly from your Colab notebook

   ```
   with io.open('/content/gdrive/Place/Of/Your/Choice/glove.6B.300d.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The top answer is fine.

Just a little addition from myside and it will start working if you get an error.

```
import zipfile
```