# Unrar all files from a folder using Windows terminal

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, rar

I am looking for a command in the windows terminal that allows me to unrar all the files from a folder. Precisely I want to replicate this bash command on windows

`find . -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -o+ {} \;`

thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer RS Finance's answer: a power shell provides an easy and clean solution. However, if that's not an option, you may achieve the same with command prompt like this (first `cd` to the correct directory),

```
for %i in (*.rar) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "%i"
```

I use 7z as my zip program. You just have to replace the path to whatever you use. If you have the path stored in you environment path, "7z.exe" without the absolute path may be enough.

Note that,

- `e` is an argument specifically for *7zip*, meaning *extract*.
- if you intend to do this in a batch script (file), you'll need double "%"-signs. See this one: [Iterate all files in a directory using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497)

Comment: thank you. That is what i wanted. I needed the normal shell because i wanted to execute it from a python script

Comment: @ÁngelDelgadoPanadero : If you're using python, I would strongly recommend you to use the `zipfile` module, instead of calling batch commands. Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Well Powershell would be a great option, something like this should do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem -File *.rar | Foreach {unrar x -o+ $_.fullname}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use UnRAR.exe supplied with WinRAR Trial. This console utility is freeware, and definitely supports all RAR format versions

e.g.

```
for %i in (*.rar) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" x "%i"
```

to extract all archives contents with relative paths or

```
for %i in (*.rar) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" e "%i"
```

to extract everything to the same folder