# Download from S3, store in /tmp/ of Lambda and unzip in /tmp/ directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I have a zip file on S3. I need to use `/tmp` folder of a Lambda for lazy-loading that I am using to store the zip file and then I need the folder to contain the unzipped contents. I am using Python for the operations. Below is the code:

```py
import sys
import zipfile
import subprocess

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('bucket', 'dependencies/dependencies.zip', '/tmp/dependencies.zip')

output = subprocess.check_output('unzip /tmp/dependencies.zip -d /tmp/')
print("Output: ", output.decode('utf-8'))
```

I am getting the error: `No such file or directory: 'unzip /tmp/dependencies.zip -d /tmp/': 'unzip /tmp/dependencies.zip -d /tmp/'
Unknown application error occurred`

I have my code outside the `lambda_handler()` for cold-start. From this I not even sure that the zipped file has been copied to `/tmp` directory since that line didn't throw any error, and also I am not able to unzip the contents. I tried removing the `/` in front of `tmp` and that didn't help either. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is to confirm that the file has been downloaded ([How to Check if a File Exists in Python – dbader.org](https://dbader.org/blog/python-check-if-file-exists)).

The problem might be that the sub-process can't find `unzip`.

I notice you have imported `zipfile`, so you could that library to unzip. From [Unzipping files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451150/174777):

```py
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/dependencies.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/')
```

Comment: Yes, I think the problem was with sub-process. `zipfile` helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The TMP folder has limited memory. Hence, I would recommend to avoid using that method. Instead, you can read the zipped file into a buffer, extract all filenames using the zipfile library. Then, you read the content of each file within the zipped file and re-upload it to S3.

```
        zipped_file = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=sourcebucketname, key=filekey)
        buffer = BytesIO(zipped_file.get()["Body"].read())
        zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
        
        for file in zipped.namelist():
            logger.info(f'current file in zipfile: {file}')
            final_file_path = file + '.extension'

            with zipped.open(file, "r") as f_in:
                content = f_in.read()
                destinationbucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(content),
                                                        final_file_path,
                                                        ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/plain"}
                                                )
```

There's also a tutorial here: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9