# Unziping zipped file in google colab

Tags: zip, google-colaboratory, unzip

i ma trying to unzip a zip file in google colab and i get this Error

***Archive:  object_detection.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of object_detection.zip or
object_detection.zip.zip, and cannot find object_detection.zip.ZIP, period.***

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!cp '/content/drive/My Drive/slim.zip' slim.zip
!unzip object_detection.zip
```

i already uploded my zip files on the drive

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem with your zip-file. Does it work locally? Otherwise, you can also try to load your file like described in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python

Comment: IS there a reason why the file you copy is called `slim.zip` and the file you unzip is called `object_detection.zip`?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and it was because I had not uploaded the file completely[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probable reason could be your zip file is corrupt.. may be you are not using proper link.. try downloading the file and then uploading on colab.. it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is fully uploaded but not unzipped using the unzip command, then try to unzip it using the below program in google colab:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('yourfile.zip', 'r') as file:
    file.extractall()
```