# How to unzip with 7z in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to unzip a archive file in a special directory.
i use subprocess as below :

```
import subprocess
INPUT_FILE = "../DEV-TESTSTATION/tmp/DLL_LOGFILE-G1R0C0.zip"
OUTPUT = "../DEV-TESTSTATION/work/LOGFILE"

subprocess.call(['7z', 'x', INPUT_FILE ,' -o'+OUTPUT ])
```

**Output :**

```
No files to process
Everything is Ok

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 2013846
```

Comment: try ```['7z', 'x', INPUT_FILE ,'-o', OUTPUT ]```

Comment: why not just use [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451150/7652544

Comment: @ewong i get this error when i test  your line : Too short switch:
-o

Comment: note that there is [py7zr](https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr)

Comment: ah, right, my bad.  you're correct in the '-o'+OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [py7xr library](https://pypi.org/project/py7zr/).

Example:

```
import py7zr 

with py7zr.SevenZipFile('abc.7z', mode='r', password='secret') as 7z: 

  7z.extractall()
```