# How to unzip many files with python

Tags: python, zip

I got more than 1000 zip files in the same folder with naming convention `output_MOJIBAKE`

> Example name: output_0aa3199eca63522b520ecfe11a4336eb_20210122_181742

How can I unzip them using Python?

Comment: Use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory to get the list of files, then use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python to unzip each one in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Try this and let me know if it worked.

```
import os
import zipfile

path = 'path/to/your/zip/files'

os.chdir(path)

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall('.')
```