# unzip file without creating temporary files

Tags: python, zip, gzip, unzip, tmp

I download a zip file from AWS S3 and unzip it. Upon unzipping, all files are saved in the `tmp/` folder.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

s3.download_file('testunzipping','DataPump_10000838.zip','/tmp/DataPump_10000838.zip')

with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/DataPump_10000838.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/')
    lstNEW = zip_ref.namelist()
```

The output of `listNEW` is something like this:

```
['DataPump_10000838/', '__MACOSX/._DataPump_10000838', 'DataPump_10000838/DockBooking', '__MACOSX/DataPump_10000838/._DockBooking', 'DataPump_10000838/LoadEquipment', '__MACOSX/DataPump_10000838/._LoadEquipment', ....]
```

LoadEquipment and DockBooking are files but the rest are not. Is it possible to unzip the file without creating those temporary files? Or is I possible to filter out the real files? Because later, I need to use the correct files and gzip them.

`$item_$unixepochtimestamp.csv.gz`

Do I use the compress function?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is, or how you're using these files once they're unzipped.  BUT... perhaps you simply want to unzip to memory (vs. writing to /tmp): https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909016/421195.  In any case, it sounds like you DEFINITELY don't want "extractall()".  Look here for alternatives: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Comment: once they are unzipped, I want to convert them into gzip and store in another s3 bucket. How can I achieve this with read? I mean how can I gzip all the unzipped files without downloading/extracting them? @paulsm4  Also, I was writing to /tmp bc of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586599/12304000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only extract certain files, you can pass a list to `extractall`:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/DataPump_10000838.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    lstNEW = list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("__MACOSX/"), zip_ref.namelist()))
    zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/', members=lstNEW)
```

The files are not temporary files, but rather macOS's way of representing resource forks in zip files that don't normally support this.

Comment: if I run the lambda function in some automatic pipeline on AWS, would this still work? I mean will it always be macOS?

Comment: Obviously this is a non-standard macOS convention that Apple can change whenever they feel like it, but so far they have always represented resource forks under the special name `__MACOSX`