# loop over files in sub zip-directories python

Tags: python, loops, file, zip, subdirectory

My txt.files are saved in zipped-subfolders as follows:

- mainfolder.zip
- mainfolder/folder1 (folder 1 is no zip-file)
- mainfolder/folder1/subfolder11.zip
- mainfolder/folder1/subfolder12.zip
- mainfolder/folder2 (folder 2 is no zip file)
- mainfolder/folder1/subfolder21.zip
- mainfolder/folder1/subfolder22.zip

I want to loop over all the text files in subfolders of the mainfolder. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: You might have to unzip your directory first. take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python

Comment: Yes, write a loop! Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help.

If the script is not in the folder with the folder to be searched, replace `os.getcwd()` with the path to the folder.

```
import os
import logging
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import unpack_archive

# unzipping all zipped folders
zip_files = Path(os.getcwd()).rglob("*.zip")
while True:
    try:
        path = next(zip_files)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except PermissionError:
        logging.exception("permission error")
    else:
         extract_dir = path.with_name(path.stem)
         unpack_archive(str(path), str(extract_dir), 'zip')

# finding and dealing with a .txt file
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
  for f in files:
    if os.path.splitext(f)[1].lower() == ".txt":
        with open(os.path.join(root, f)) as fi:
            lines = fi.readlines()
            print("File: ",os.path.join(root, f),"\ncontent: ", lines)
            # all what you want do with file...
```

Nice day :)