# Unzipping with specific name

Tags: python, zip, unzip, python-zipfile

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python), is there an option to rename the file when extracting it? Or what is the best solution to do so?

Didn't find anything on the documentation

Comment: You want to `rename` the directory after extraction or `rename`  files in the directory' ?

Comment: In the ZIP File there will be only one file and I want to rename it like the folder (except the .zip extension ;))

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Did you read documentation for `zipfile`? It has `extract()` and `read()` - and one of then can be useful for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two methods:

1. Using [ZipFile.read()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.read)

   You can get data from zip file using `ZipFile.read()` and write it with `new name` using standard `open()`, `write()`

   ```
   import zipfile

   z = zipfile.ZipFile('image.zip')

   for f in z.infolist():
       data = z.read(f)
       with open('new_name.png', 'wb') as fh:
           fh.write(data)
   ```
2. Using [zipfile.extract()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) with [ZipInfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo)

   You can change name before using `extract()`

   ```
   import zipfile

   z = zipfile.ZipFile('image.zip')

   for f in z.infolist():
       #print(f.filename)
       #print(f.orig_filename)
       f.filename = 'new_name.png'
       z.extract(f)
   ```

   This version can automatically create subfolders if you use

   ```
   f.filename = 'folder/subfolder/new_name.png'
   z.extract(f)

   f.filename = 'new_name.png'
   z.extract(f, 'folder/subfolder')
   ```