# Python - run Bash command and specify response

Tags: python, bash, unzip

I have a folder that contains zip files. I want to be able to unzip them, and specify "A[ll]" when asked "replace file.diz".

My current code is:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir("path-to-directory")
for i in os.listdir():
    if i.endswith("zip"):
        subprocess.run("unzip '*.zip'", shell=True)
```

At this point I am asked:

```
Archive:  archivea.zip
replace file.diz? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

What Python command can I use to specify A as input when Bash returns that question?
Or, if I want to specify y as input (when the Bash command gets to archiveb.zip), how do I do that each time automatically in Python?
Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't put `*.zip` inside quotes, that prevents expanding the wildcard.

Comment: Why not just use a python package to unzip the files? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python) an example

Comment: You can use the `-o` option to force overwriting files without asking.

Comment: BTW, `subprocess.run(['unzip', '*.zip'])` simplifies everything -- no quotes, no `shell=True`, no copy of `/bin/sh` being invoked at runtime. @Barmar, the intent is to have `unzip` itself expand the wildcard here; otherwise the first argument is treated as a zip file name and other arguments as names of files within that zip file to expand.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar said in the comments, you can specify -o option to unzip:

> `-o` overwrite existing files without prompting. This is a dangerous option, so use it with care. (It is often used with `-f`, however, and is the only way to overwrite directory EAs under OS/2.)

In general, if you want to specify a response you can use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) libary