# How can you zip or unzip from the script using ONLY Windows' built-in capabilities?

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

In Windows you can zip some files by

> right click → *Send to* → *Compressed (zipped) folder*

And unzip by double clicking on the `.zip` file and extract the files.

Is there a way to apply those abilities from a script (.bat file) **without the need to install any third-party software**?

Comment: Clues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021557/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-command-line

Comment: use 7zip https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm

Comment: This question [was comprehensibly answered on Super User in 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili/111266#111266), 2 1/2 years prior.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Back in 2013, that was not possible. Microsoft didn't provide any executable for this.

See this link for some VBS way to do this.
https://superuser.com/questions/201371/create-zip-folder-from-the-command-line-windows

From Windows 8 on, .NET Framework 4.5 is installed by default, with [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) and PowerShell available, one can write scripts to achieve this, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843122/71312

Comment: This isn't correct given that PS allows this and is pre-installed on Windows and is available via the command line.

Comment: @DanAtkinson Then you're answering the wrong question; the question asked for a way to "apply those abilities from the command line"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Well "command line" refers generically to any command line, not specifically CMD/COMMAND, and PS definitely is a command line, as is bash, sh, rsh on *nix.  But just to go one further, since you can run powershell from the command line, it does answer the question even if you want to believe that cmd/command is the one and only command line.

Comment: It *was* possible back in 2013 (without installing any extra software). See [the Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili/111266#111266). It has been possible since [Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) came out in 2001. The built-in ZIP functionality in Windows XP can be leveraged because it is exposed through a [COM interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model).

Answer (score 192):

To expand upon Steven Penny's PowerShell solution, you can incorporate it into a batch file by calling `powershell.exe` like this:

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('foo.zip', 'bar'); }"
```

As Ivan Shilo said, this won't work with PowerShell 2, it requires PowerShell 3 or greater and .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Actually, this was made available in .NET 4.5.

Comment: For those (like me) who wonder how to extract into the actual directory (instead of creating a new directory) simply set the target parameter to `'.'`, e.g.: `powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('foo.zip', '.'); }"`

Comment: What is the purpose of `& {}`? With PS5 this works, too: `powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('foo.zip', '.');"`

Answer (score 149):

If you have Java installed, you can compress to a ZIP archive using the `jar` command:

```
jar -cMf targetArchive.zip sourceDirectory
```

> c = Creates a new archive file.
>
> M = Specifies that a manifest file should not be added to the archive.
>
> f = Indicates target file name.

Comment: awesome, thanks, just what I was looking for... 
FYI - I had to remove the minus char in DOS... e.g. jar cMf target.zip sourceDir

Comment: Not bad, but you need the JDK installed, not the JRE.

Comment: Is this covered by *"... using **ONLY** Windows' **built-in** capabilities?"* (my emphasis)

Comment: Also we can set `alias zip='jar -cMf'` in bash for the same so don't have to remember the `jar` parameters

Answer (score 100):

#### PowerShell 5.0

From [**`Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841357.aspx) you can use:

- [**`Compress-Archive`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841358.aspx)
- [**`Expand-Archive`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841359.aspx)

E.g.:

- Create `result.zip` from the entire `Test` folder:

  ```
  Compress-Archive -Path C:\Test -DestinationPath C:\result
  ```
- Extract the content of `result.zip` in the specified `Test` folder:

  ```
  Expand-Archive -Path result.zip -DestinationPath C:\Test
  ```

Comment: This works great, thank you. For anyone ending up down here, you can use `powershell Compress-Archive -Path C:\SomeFile.ext -DestinationPath C:\SomeFile.zip` right from command line without needing to make a script (assuming you have Powershell v5 installed, which you can do at least going back to Windows 7).

Comment: Works great, add -Force option if you are planning on rerunning it.

Comment: @Beems, Thank you! But I think you mad the path / destination the other way round?

Comment: This works, but the archive is compressed differently then what happens if you use the windows explorer "Sent To -> compressed (zipped) folder"     The powershell version is bigger and some programs can't extract

Comment: Compress-Archive has a maximum file limit of 2GB on the input file

Comment: I'm also noticing a similar issue as @Eric. The compressed file is different from the one created using "Send To -> compressed (zipped) folder".

Answer (score 37):

It isn't exactly a ZIP, but the only way to compress a file using Windows tools is:

```
makecab <source> <dest>.cab
```

To decompress:

```
expand <source>.cab <dest>
```

Advanced example (from ss64.com):

```
Create a self extracting archive containing movie.mov:
C:\> makecab movie.mov "temp.cab"
C:\> copy /b "%windir%\system32\extrac32.exe"+"temp.cab" "movie.exe"
C:\> del /q /f "temp.cab"
```

More information: [makecab](http://ss64.com/nt/makecab.html), [expand](http://ss64.com/nt/expand.html), [makecab advanced uses](http://ss64.com/nt/makecab-directives.html)

Comment: No, [it is not the only way to compress a file using Windows tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-script-using-only-windows-built-in-capabiliti/24323413#comment100524315_17546190).

Answer (score 32):

**Using 7-Zip:**

**Zip**: you have a folder `foo`, and want to zip it to `myzip.zip`

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a  -r myzip.zip -w foo -mem=AES256
```

**Unzip**: you want to unzip it (`myzip.zip`) to current directory (`./`)

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x  myzip.zip  -o./ -y -r
```

Comment: Please notice the question: `without the need to install any 3rd party`

Comment: @ Roland : By specifying this switch( -w), you can set the working directory where the temporary base archive file will be built. After the temporary base archive file is built, it is copied over the original archive; then, the temporary file is deleted.

Comment: @Monir understood. But why? Without the `-w` switch the temporary base archive will be in the same directory, so what do you gain by using `-w` as opposed to just not using that switch?

Comment: @Roland: Yes you are right . we are not gaining something until we want to specify a certain a path.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a VBScript script wrapped in a BAT file. This code works on a relative PATH.

There isn't any need for any third-party tools or dependencies. Just set `SOURCEDIR` and `OUTPUTZIP`.

Filename: ZipUp.bat

```
echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") > _zipup.vbs
echo InputFolder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)) >> _zipup.vbs
echo ZipFile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1)) >> _zipup.vbs

' Create empty ZIP file.
echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar) >> _zipup.vbs

echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >> _zipup.vbs
echo Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items >> _zipup.vbs
echo objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> _zipup.vbs

echo ' Keep script waiting until compression is done
echo Do Until objShell.NameSpace( ZipFile ).Items.Count = objShell.NameSpace( InputFolder ).Items.Count >> _zipup.vbs
echo     WScript.Sleep 200 >> _zipup.vbs
echo Loop >> _zipup.vbs

CScript  _zipup.vbs  %SOURCEDIR%  %OUTPUTZIP%

del _zipup.vbs
```

Example usage

```
SET SOURCEDIR=C:\Some\Path
SET OUTPUTZIP=C:\Archive.zip
CALL ZipUp
```

Alternatively, you can parametrize this file by replacing the line `CScript  _zipup.vbs  %SOURCEDIR%  %OUTPUTZIP%` with `CScript  _zipup.vbs  %1  %2`, in which case it can be even more easily called from by simply calling `CALL ZipUp C:\Source\Dir C:\Archive.zip`.

Comment: The line which creates the initial zip file needs to be escaped otherwise it does not end up in the script.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go (like in [the Super User question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-script-using-only-windows-built-in-capabiliti/24323413#comment100524315_17546190)).

Comment: Why re-write the VBS file again and again each time you use the command?

Answer (score 7):

I've been looking to answer this exact question and from my research, DiryBoy's response seems to be accurate.

I found the compact.exe program compresses files but not to create a highly compressed file (or set of files).  It is similar to the option you get when right clicking on a drive letter or partition in Windows. You get the option to do cleanup (remove temp files, etc) as well as compress files.  The compressed files are still accessible but are just compressed to create space on a drive that is low on space.

I also found compress.exe which I did happen to have on my computer.  It isn't natively on most windows machines and is part of the 2003 resource kit.  It does make a zipped file of sorts but it is really more similar to files from a windows setup disk (has the underscore as the last character of the file extension or name).  And the extract.exe command extracts those files.

However, the mantra is, if it can be done natively via the GUI then there is likely a way to do it via batch, .vbs, or some other type of script within the command line.  Since windows has had the 'send to' option to create a zip file, I knew there had to be a way to do it via command line and I found some options.

Here is a great link that shows how to zip a file using windows native commands.

https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili

I tested it with a directory containing multiple nested files and folders and it worked perfectly.  Just follow the format of the command line.

There is also a way to unzip the files via command line which I found as well.  One way, just brings open an explorer window showing what the content of the zipped file is.  Some of these also use Java which isn't necessarily native to windows but is so common that it nearly seems so.

https://superuser.com/questions/149489/does-windows-7-have-unzip-at-the-command-line-installed-by-default

[How to unzip a file using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021557/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-command-line)

Comment: No, [DiryBoy's response is *not* accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-script-using-only-windows-built-in-capabiliti/24323413#comment100524315_17546190)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do this as part of a script then the best way is to use Java. Assuming the bin directory is in your path (in most cases), you can use the command line:

```
jar xf test.zip
```

If Java is not on your path, reference it directly:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin>jar xf test.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a problem with all these solutions.

They're **not exactly** the same, and they all create files that have a slight size difference compared to the `RMB --> send to --> compressed (zipped) folder` when made from the same source folder. The closest size-difference I have had is 300 KB difference (script > manual), made with:

```
powershell Compress-Archive -Path C:\sourceFolder -CompressionLevel Fastest -DestinationPath C:\destinationArchive.zip
```

(Notice the *-CompressionLevel*. [There are three possible values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6#parameters): Fastest, NoCompression & Optimal, (Default: Optimal))

I wanted to make a .bat file that should automatically compress a WordPress plugin folder I'm working on, into a .zip archive, so I can upload it into the WordPress site and test the plugin.

But for some reason it doesn't work with any of these automatic compressions, *but* it does work with the manual RMB compression, witch I find really strange.

And the script-generated .zip files actually break the WordPress plugins to the point where they can't be activated, and they can also not be deleted from inside WordPress. I have to SSH into the "back side" of the server and delete the uploaded plugin files themselves, manually. While the manually RMB-generated files work normally.

Comment: What is *"wbr"* and *"RMB"*?

Comment: RMB = Right Mouse Button. 
<wbr> = a HTML tag that indicates a "Word BReak opportunity" to the browser (removed, because it didn't work).

Answer (score 3):

This is an updated version to the answer provided by @PodTech.io

This version has all of the vbs code correctly escaped in the batch file. 
It's also created into a sub-routine, which can be called with a single line from anywhere in your batch script:

```
:: === Main code:

call :ZipUp "C:\Some\Path" "C:\Archive.zip"


:: === SubRoutines:

:ZipUp
::Arguments: Source_folder, destination_zip
(
    echo:Set fso = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    echo:InputFolder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName^(WScript.Arguments.Item^(0^)^)
    echo:ZipFile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName^(WScript.Arguments.Item^(1^)^)
    echo:
    echo:' Create empty ZIP file.
    echo:CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^).CreateTextFile^(ZipFile, True^).Write "PK" ^& Chr^(5^) ^& Chr^(6^) ^& String^(18, vbNullChar^)
    echo:
    echo:Set objShell = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
    echo:Set source = objShell.NameSpace^(InputFolder^).Items
    echo:objShell.NameSpace^(ZipFile^).CopyHere^(source^)
    echo:
    echo:' Keep script waiting until compression is done
    echo:Do Until objShell.NameSpace^( ZipFile ^).Items.Count = objShell.NameSpace^( InputFolder ^).Items.Count
    echo:    WScript.Sleep 200
    echo:Loop
)>_zipup.vbs
CScript //Nologo _zipup.vbs "%~1" "%~2"
del _zipup.vbs
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 3):

### Shell.Application

With Shell.Application you can emulate the way explorer.exe zips files and folders
The script is called [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat):

```
:: unzip content of a zip to given folder.content of the zip will be not preserved (-keep no).Destination will be not overwritten (-force no)
call zipjs.bat unzip -source C:\myDir\myZip.zip -destination C:\MyDir -keep no -force no

:: lists content of a zip file and full paths will be printed (-flat yes)
call zipjs.bat list -source C:\myZip.zip\inZipDir -flat yes

:: lists content of a zip file and the content will be list as a tree (-flat no)
call zipjs.bat list -source C:\myZip.zip -flat no

:: prints uncompressed size in bytes
zipjs.bat getSize -source C:\myZip.zip

:: zips content of folder without the folder itself
call zipjs.bat zipDirItems -source C:\myDir\ -destination C:\MyZip.zip -keep yes -force no

:: zips file or a folder (with the folder itslelf)
call zipjs.bat zipItem -source C:\myDir\myFile.txt -destination C:\MyZip.zip -keep yes -force no

:: unzips only part of the zip with given path inside
call zipjs.bat unZipItem -source C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir\InzipFile -destination C:\OtherDir -keep no -force yes
call zipjs.bat unZipItem -source C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir -destination C:\OtherDir 

:: adds content to a zip file
call zipjs.bat addToZip -source C:\some_file -destination C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir -keep no
call zipjs.bat addToZip -source  C:\some_file -destination C:\myDir\myZip.zip
```

### MAKECAB

Makecab is the default compressing tool coming with windows. Though it can use different compression algorithms (including zip) file format is always a `.cab` file. With some extensions it can be used on linux machines too.

compressing a file:

```
makecab file.txt "file.cab"
```

Compressing an entire folder needs a little bit more work. Here a directory is compressed with [cabDir.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/makecab/cabdir.bat):

```
call cabDir.bat ./myDir compressedDir.cab
```

Uncompressing is rather easy with `expand` command:

```
EXPAND cabfile -F:* .
```

More hackier way is by creating self-extracting executable with extrac32 command:

```
copy /b "%windir%\system32\extrac32.exe"+"mycab.cab" "expandable.exe"
call expandable.exe
```

### TAR

With the build 17063 of windows we have the tar command:

```
::compress directory
tar -cvf archive.tar c:\my_dir
::extract to dir
tar -xvf archive.tar.gz -C c:\data
```

### .NET tools

.net (and powershell) offers a lot of ways to compress and uncompress files. The most straightforward is with gzip stream. The script is called [gzipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/gzipJS.bat):

```
::zip
call gzipjs.bat -c my.file my.zip
::unzip
call gzipjs.bat -u my.zip my.file
```

Answer (score 3):

Newer windows builds include tar.exe.
tar.exe can be used in the cmd or windows batch files.

```
//Compress a folder:
tar -caf aa.zip c:\aa
```

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me (in 2021):

```
tar -xf test.zip
```

This will unzip the **test** in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Adding upon @Jason Duffett's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843122/3002584) and its comments, here's a script that **gets input and output** (file name and directory name, respectively) from the user:

```
@echo off
set input=%1
set output=%2
powershell.exe "Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('%input%', '%output%');"
```

Usage:

```
unzip.bat path\to\file.zip path\to\output\directory
```

Comment: The PowerShell from a batch file approach has 2 little issues: 1. There is no text output during the process to see the progress of what is being extracted. 2. The process can't be interrupted with Ctrl+C or any other key combination. Only killing the "powershell.exe" process from the Task Manager stops it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to unzip a zip file with a batch file:

```
@echo off
::unziper
set /p zip=zip:
powershell -Command "Expand-Archive %zip%"
echo done
pause
```

I'm posting this in case if anyone needs it.
why would you edit my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Noam Manos, we can improve the zipping a little more by using alias in `.bashrc` file:

`alias zip='jar -cMf'`

and then the command (in bash terminal) would be

`zip target.zip dir1 dir2`

**Note:** you should have java and git bash installed and setup in windows for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, but as the question stated: `without the need to install any third-party software`. so if I need to install Java and GitBash, I would just install ZIP.

Comment: I guess, the original question I asked (8 years ago) was when we have several data-center world-wide with physical instances (it was before the cloud), so new software installation would required us to install it manually on ~100 machines which is what I tried to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to compress an entire folder and subfolders

**compact /c /s "C:\Temp\my_folder" /I /Q**

To Decompress

**compact /u /s:"C:\Temp\my_folder" /I /Q**

While c stands for compress and u for decompress

Comment: This is unrelated to the question. The `compact` command controls the compression status of files/directories on an NTFS partition. It has nothing to do with zipping or unzipping `.zip` files. Type `compact /?` on the Windows command line for information about this command.