# Compress/Zip a file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to Compress/Zip an xls file which is generated by my macro.
I have IZarc installed on my machine.

Can somebody please suggest the batch code to zip an xlx file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you zip or unzip from the command prompt using ONLY Windows' built-in capabilities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca)

Answer (score 0):

This is copy-pasted from [this link](http://comptb.cects.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/testizarc.txt).

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Replace space in hour with zero if it's less than 10
SET hr=%time:~0,2%
IF %hr% lss 10 SET hr=0%hr:~1,1%

REM This sets the date like this:  mm-dd-yr-hrminsecs1/100secs
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%-%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%

REM Use IZArc to Zip files in folder c:\testzip and place the zip archive in C:\testmove

ECHO.
ECHO Zipping all files in C:\testzip and moving archive to c:\testmove
ECHO.
izarcc -a -cx "C:\testmove\xxxx_%TODAY%.zip" "C:\testzip\*.*"
ECHO.

ECHO Delete the files in orginal folder
DEL "C:\testzip\*.*"

PAUSE
```

For completeness, this script looks good without any cuts.

Comment: But windows doesn't come with IZArc

Comment: If **@user93353**'s comment don't help, Third link in [this page](http://www.izarc.org/download.html) would help I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

this utility might be something for you

https://mega.nz/#!4VZnFb6T!nqv0JTqJYLff7e44WQS6-VvhAU-Cs7WBnHZXFd9FRWc

inside there will be 2 .exe files. one for zipping and one for un-zipping. there will also be an .txt file tells you how to use it

virus-total scan
https://www.virustotal.com/da/file/5a38d605e943a1f5ce185e19eb9bda0969d370e7aad9a03575fab7852ed48157/analysis/1488190750/

***EXAMPLE OF USAGE:***

**Zip Files**

```
@echo off
title Zip files in folder
zip.exe zippedxlxfiles path/to/xlxfiles/*.*
pause
```

**Zip a single file**

```
@echo off
title Zip files in folder
zip.exe zippedxlxfiles path/to/xlxfiles/filename.xlx
pause
```

Note this will zip all the files in the folder you choose

**Un-zip Files**

```
@echo off
title Zip files in folder
unzip.exe zippedxlxfiles
pause
```

Note that this will unzip the files in the same directory as the exe itself