# Zipping file using command line

Tags: command-line, windows-7, zip

**Background**
I have an application, that for deployment I zip the installation files before shipping it.
The zipping is mainly for:

1. Publishing the files in a single folder.
2. Giving the folder a unique name for differentiating it from other versions (e.g. appName_ver1 and appName_ver2).

**My question**
Is there a way, in windows 7, to do a zip in command line? (I'm planning to perform deployment using a script).

**Additional information**

1. I don't mind using external tools (e.g. 7zip) on the **deploying** machine.
2. I cannot count on any software being installed on the installing machine, so windows 7 should be able to open the zipped folder using a double click in windows explorer.
3. The files are rather small, so I an not worried about how good the compression is.
4. After a quick search in Google, what I came was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca), which is not realy my case.

Comment: `7-Zip` can create `ZIP` files too which are native in Windows 7.  The command you need depends on `folder-to-be-archived`, `zip-name` and if there are `subdirectories to be included`

Comment: @foxidrive I was not aware of that. I tested it, and it worked. If you post this as an answer I will accept the answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`7-Zip` can create `ZIP` files too which are native in Windows 7.