# Reconstructing docx from xml files

Tags: xml, zip, docx

From what I have read, docx files are zipped collections of xml file. On Windows 7, (the only OS on which I have tried this), if I save a file, say f.docx from Word, then exit Word and change the file name to f.zip, I can unzip the bundle and read the component files. But if I then remove then re-zip the f folder (without any modifications) and change the extension back to docx, I then get an error saying that "The file f.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents". And when I look at the details, it says, "Microsoft Office cannot open this file because some parts are missing or invalid."

Question: Why is that? And how *can* the component pieces be reassembled into a valid docx file?

A similar question is asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/411911/re-zipped-docx-files-dont-open-in-word) but the offered solution does not work. As I've noted above, I'm not altering anything in the folders, nor even opening the files. Although I cannot see why it would be of relevance, my method for rezipping the file is to use the context-menu command "Send to compressed (zipped) folder".

Comment: the solution you cited tells you to do it from cmd.exe. Are you following the instruction?

Comment: Indeed! The [solution](http://superuser.com/questions/411911/re-zipped-docx-files-dont-open-in-word) that I cited has a comment that with some words that I missed, namely "...and as long as I do all the zipping/viewing/unzipping in the terminal it's fine"

One problem of course is that Windows 7 does not have a zip command built in, and there is also a little glitch to be careful of. So, I have written my own answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Pawel noted in his comment, the thing to do is ensure that the rezipping is done from the command line. In the absence of a built-in zip command in Windows 7 (I was unable to get the PowerShell solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca) to work) one can use 7-zip for the recreation of the zipped archive; unzipping with Windows 7 context menu appears not to be the problem. There is something to be careful of using 7-zip. Assume that foo.docx has been renamed to foo.zip and uncompressed with the context menu to folder foo. Then, when it comes time to rezip the component files with 7-zip, do not zip the foo folder. Instead, descend into the foo folder, select the component files and folders, and the use 7-zip to zip those components into a foo.zip folder than can be renamed back to foo.docx.

Comment: Man i just lost my work today , and been bashing my head why i couldn't get it back. I needed to fix some of the xml file in order for it to become valid and i zipped it back wrong , with the folder , just like you said , now i zipped it right and it worked ! thank you so much

Comment: @Pure_eyes I'm glad it was helpful. You could mark it up! If you think it is correct, you could mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

What I do to modify docx, xlsx or pptx files w/o fiddling with zipping:

1. add `.zip` to file name (`file.docx.zip`)
2. navigate to the file I need to change e.g. `/word/document.xml`
3. copy file outside of `.zip` folder
4. modify the file
5. copy file back into `.zip` folder (sometimes I need to delete the original file rather than overwriting it)
6. remove `.zip` from file name (`file.docx`)
7. done, open file in Word

Comment: Some zip file viewers let you see the contents of the zip directory, open files, edit and save them back into the zip, without unzipping/re-zipping everything. [I used Engrampa on Ubuntu, but I suspect it's possible with others].