# Chef Selenium: WmiLite:WmiException on Windows Server 2008

Tags: selenium, wmi, chef-infra, selenium-grid

On Windows 2008 & 2008 R2 the following exception is thrown during Chef `selenium_node` installation:

```
FATAL: WmiLite::WmiException: An error occurred connecting to the WMI service for namespace 'root/cimv2'.
The namespace may not be valid, access may not be allowed to the WMI service, or the WMI service may not be available.
(in OLE method `ConnectServer': )
OLE error code:800705AF in SWbemLocator
The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
HRESULT error code:0x80020009
Exception occurred.
```

The error does NOT occur on Windows 2012 & 2012 R2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chef Selenium: rubyzip failure to allocate memory issue on Windows Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976315/chef-selenium-rubyzip-failure-to-allocate-memory-issue-on-windows-server-2008)

Comment: You can get this stacktrace which is rarer but still different from rubyzip stacktrace.  They both have the same underlying cause.

Comment: Please edit your original post with additional / new information. If this is a new question, please clarify how is it **different**  from your previous post.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/chef/knife-windows#nodes:

The Chef and Ohai gem installations (that occur during bootstrap) take more memory than the default 150MB WinRM allocates per shell on older versions of Windows (prior to Windows Server 2012) -- this can slow down bootstrap. Optionally increase the memory limit to 300MB with the following command:

```
winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}
```

Also note:

Windows 2008R2 and earlier versions require an extra configuration for MaxTimeoutms to avoid WinRM::WinRMHTTPTransportError: Bad HTTP response error while bootstrapping. It should be atleast 300000.

```
winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms=300000}
```