# check if a file exists in zip archive

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I'm using windows 7 ultimate and I want to check on the command line whether or not a file exists inside a zip archive.
I'd prefer if the procedure does not include downloading other stuff.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This site is mostly designed for very specific problems in your code. Usually, a good question contains a small amount of code, what you tried and what didn't work. If your question doesn't really contain a question and just asks for code, chances are you won't get a reply.

Comment: Not identical, but very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca/26843122#26843122).

Comment: I have c:\file.zip and file.txt inside that archive. 
For a normal file I would do 
if exist c:\file.zip echo file exist 
But that is a zip archive.
In windows command prompt i tried 
if exist c:\file.zip\file.txt echo file exist
But no luck, please someone help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat):

```
call zipjs.bat list -source "C:\myZip.zip" -flat yes|find /i "filename" && (
  echo file does  exists in the zip
  color 
)|| (
  echo file does NOT exists in the zip
)
```

Comment: finally that works. thank you so much @ npocmaka