# How to unzip a WAR file in command line

Tags: java, command-line, jar, war, unzip

**First, I know it's possible to unzip a WAR file using `jar` in command line.**

The problem is that on the target machine, there is no JDK installed, only the JRE. And we can't rely on Windows to unzip the file because it does not support well long path.

How it's possible to unzip a WAR file in command line when you only have the JRE installed?

Comment: Use any archiver that supports **zip**.

Comment: Have a look at the answers in this thread [zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca).

Comment: @SubOptimal thx, it seems like [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory support long path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record I will share my solution that I've got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca).

I point in my question that I had also a problem with long path, a problem that I've solved with [New-PSDrive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx), a function that let you map a temporary drive. I've only mapped a temporary drive on the working folder where I unzip stuff.

```
function Unzip-File($file) {    
    $path = [io.path]::GetDirectoryName($file.FullName)
    $filename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file.FullName)
    $targetPath = Join-Path $path $filename;

    # Check if the directory exists.    
    if(Test-Path $targetPath) {
        # Remove the directory before unzipping.
        Remove-Item $targetPath -recurse
    }

    # Unzip file.
    Add-Type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($file, $targetPath)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

WAR file is just a ZIP file, you can unzip it using any Zip tool (like 7-Zip). If you don't have an access admin account, you can just download [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable) of any zip archive, which doesn't require admin password.

Comment: I can't assumed that there is a third-party unzipping tool like 7-Zip on the server. With the help of @SubOtimal, I've found a solution.