# .Jar file won't open

Tags: java, file, jar

I'm trying to open OpenRocket from my downloads folder, but it keeps on defaulting it to my JGrasp IDE. I tried opening with:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe 
but it still won't work.

Bottom line. I can't open .jar files anymore because I can't find the right .exe file to open it with! What do I do?

Thanks

Comment: What exact command do you use to run the jar ?

Comment: Not sure which you are trying to do, but you can use `java -jar` to [execute the jar from the command line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) or [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021557/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-command-line) for command-line extraction tools.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run OpenRocket, you need to provide it to java with the `-jar` flag. In your case, from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar OpenRocket-14.06.jar
```

Comment: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"  -jar OpenRocket-14.06.jar` to handle the spaces in the path if launching from the command line

Answer (score 0):

According to the [openrocket site](http://openrocket.sourceforge.net/download.html), running is as simple as `java -jar OpenRocket-14.06.jar`. Do note, though that the Sun runtime is recommended. Indeed, I just verified the command on my system.