# How can I access attributes of manifest file in DOS?

Tags: batch-file, jar, manifest, dos

Basically I am facing issue in extracting the jar.I tried using the following command to extract jar file:-

**jar xvf myjar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST**

But java path is not set for that system.i.e. jdk is not added to the path environment variable.So jar xvf command cannot run.
Is there any other way to extract the jar file or accessing the manifest file without extracting the jar?

Comment: Did you even search before posting?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Comment: I think you are not getting me. I want to access the contents of manifest file in DOS.

Comment: Please, again, do some research.  The `JAR` file is simply a `ZIP` file.  Within this file you can find the desired file.  On my workstation, I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib` which contains the JAR `management-agent.jar` and I can open this using `WinZip` which I had hoped would help illustrate a path you can research.  Many UnZipping software these days has `DOS` executables which can be scripted to extract the `JAR` file and open `MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unzip a file using the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021557/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [How to unzip a file using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021557/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-command-line) which I found using the search string `stack overflow unzip jar dos`

Comment: I can't use any software.

Comment: What about using `PUSHD \\server\c$\folder` where the dos executable file is located?

Comment: pushd saves the current working directory in the memory and optionally changes to a new directory.
How can **PUSHD \\server\c$\folder** extract the jar file ?

Comment: Using `PUSHD` you are able to navigate to a server's share which contains executables since you stated you cannot use any software.  This means the software is not installed on the computer.